# Execute javascript after clicked on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to execute a javascript after a specific link was clicked on my page. I found this :

```
<a href="#" id="myHref">Click me</a>

$("#myHref").on('click', function() {
document.getElementById(".myDiv").style.flexGrow = "5";
 window.location = "http://www.google.com";});`
```

However, my "a" tag doesn't have an id and I can't edit the HTML :

```
<a class="position_top align_center" title="anglais" href="blabla" lang="en-US">
```

Can I use the title as a selector like this ?

```
$("blablaanglais").on('click', function() {
document.getElementById(".myDiv").style.flexGrow = "5";
 window.location = "http://www.google.com";});`
```

Or there is another way to do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you can the title or the href or both or  .... have you tried ?

Comment: while you can execute javascript when it is clicked, you wont be able to run javascript after you change `window.location` since you are changing the webpage itself.  You are just trying to run some javascript prior to navigating away from your website, no?

Comment: It was just an example, my function isn't the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `title` selector with square brackets.

`$("a[title='anglais']").on(....)`

A good reference on jQuery selectors can be seen here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the title as a selector or another attribute

```
$("a[title='anglais']")
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access this node:

```
<a class="position_top align_center" title="anglais" href="blabla" lang="en-US">
```

The most straightforward approach in standard javascript is:

```
var specificLink = document.querySelector('a[title="anglais"]');
```